# How to properly animate shapes within a canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to recreate a very very old arcade game called [Pong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiShX2pTz9A) (check out the hyperlink please)

I've created everything except for the ball, but when I try to draw/animate it, some really weird behavior arises:

---

**NOTE: VIEW THE GAME IN FULL-SCREEN MODE!**

---

Here's my code: https://codepen.io/Undefined_Variable/pen/Pavzvd

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Pong.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="GameCanvas">No support for you, scrub!</canvas>
    <!--Start of the script-->
    <script>
        var GameCanvas = document.body.querySelector('#GameCanvas');
        var ctx = GameCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var WindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var WindowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        var x = 0;
        var speedX = 0;
        var speedY = 0;

        var playerOne = {
            x1: (0.02 * WindowWidth),
            y1: (0.45* WindowHeight),
            x2: 30,
            y2: 70
        }
        var playerTwo = {
            x1: (0.96 * WindowWidth),
            y1: (0.45 * WindowHeight),
            x2: 30,
            y2: 70
        }
        var LineOne = {
            y1: 20
        }
        var LineTwo = {
            y1: 650
        }
        var ball = {
            x: 60,
            y: 60,
            radius: 30,
            speedX: 2,
            speedY: 2,
            color: 'green'
        }

        var Ball = {
            x1: 782.5 + speedX,
            y1: 400 + speedY,
            x2: 40,
            y2: 40,
        }

        GameCanvas.width = WindowWidth;
        GameCanvas.height = WindowHeight;

        window.onload = function initial() {

            window.addEventListener('resize', function (evt) {
                GameCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                GameCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                playerTwo.x1 = (0.96 * window.innerWidth);
                DrawDashesWhileLoop();
            });

            DrawPlayers();
            DrawDashesWhileLoop();
            DrawBall();
            BallMovement();
        }

            function DrawDashesWhileLoop() {
                var y = 70;
                while (y < 730) {
                    y += 30;
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                    ctx.fillRect(GameCanvas.width / 2, y, 5, 15);
                        ctx.restore();
                }
            }

        function DrawPlayers() {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(playerOne.x1, playerOne.y1, playerOne.x2, playerOne.y2);
            ctx.fillRect(playerTwo.x1, playerTwo.y1, playerTwo.x2, playerTwo.y2);
            ctx.restore();
            requestAnimationFrame(DrawPlayers);
        }
        window.addEventListener("keydown", movePlayer, false);

        function movePlayer(e) {

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GameCanvas.width, GameCanvas.height);

            if (e.keyCode == 83) {
                console.log('S pressed!');
                playerOne.y1 += 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 87) {
                console.log('W pressed!');
                playerOne.y1 -= 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                console.log('Top arrow pressed!');
                playerTwo.y1 -= 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                console.log('Bottom arrow pressed!');
                playerTwo.y1 += 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode > 0) {
                DrawDashesWhileLoop();
                BarCollision(playerOne);
                BarCollision(playerTwo);
            }
        }
        function BarCollision(player) {
            if (player.y1 < 10) {
                console.log("AAAAAAAA");
                player.y1 = 10;
            }
            if (player.y1 > 820) {
                console.log("AAAAAAAA");
                player.y1 = 820;
            }
        }
        function BallMovement() {
            DrawBall();
            speedX = 10;
            speedY = 10;
            requestAnimationFrame(BallMovement);
        }
        function DrawBall() {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(Ball.x1, Ball.y1, Ball.x2, Ball.y2)
            ctx.restore();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#GameCanvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    margin-bottom: 10vh;
    margin-right: 12vw;
    margin-left: 12vw;
}

body {
    font-family: 'ArcadeFont';
    font-size: 5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArcadeFont';
    src: url('fonts/ARCADECLASSIC.TTF');
}
```

Please tell me how to fix it (I want the ball to start moving rightwards with speed of "10px/60 frames" when the page loads)

Comment: Please define "really weird behavior".  It is unclear what you are asking right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help get you on the right track:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVgKOL/

Basically, you aren't actually changing the ball's values. You'll notice in the DrawBall (which should be camelcase btw), I added the clearRect method as well as added 2 to the Ball's x1 value, causing it to move to the right. I didn't calculate for your specific speed of 10px per 60 frames, so please excuse me, but that's just a bit of math on your part. You could do the altering of the Ball's coordinates in its own methods, since you will obviously want to do that in different ways depending on collisions, etc. Also, you will have to redraw the middle dotted line when the ball passes over, since clearRect will erase it, too. (though, if you move one of the players, that will also trigger the middle line to redraw). Hope this helps!

```js
var GameCanvas = document.body.querySelector('#GameCanvas');
        var ctx = GameCanvas.getContext("2d");
        var WindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var WindowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        var x = 0;
        var speedX = 0;
        var speedY = 0;

        var playerOne = {
            x1: (0.02 * WindowWidth),
            y1: (0.45* WindowHeight),
            x2: 30,
            y2: 70
        }
        var playerTwo = {
            x1: (0.96 * WindowWidth),
            y1: (0.45 * WindowHeight),
            x2: 30,
            y2: 70
        }
        var LineOne = {
            y1: 20
        }
        var LineTwo = {
            y1: 650
        }
        var ball = {
            x: 60,
            y: 60,
            radius: 30,
            speedX: 2,
            speedY: 2,
            color: 'green'
        }

        var Ball = {
            x1: 782.5 + speedX,
            y1: 400 + speedY,
            x2: 40,
            y2: 40,
        }

        GameCanvas.width = WindowWidth;
        GameCanvas.height = WindowHeight;

        window.onload = function initial() {

            window.addEventListener('resize', function (evt) {
                GameCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                GameCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                playerTwo.x1 = (0.96 * window.innerWidth);
                DrawDashesWhileLoop();
            });

            DrawPlayers();
            DrawDashesWhileLoop();
            DrawBall();
            BallMovement();
        }

            function DrawDashesWhileLoop() {
                var y = 70;
                while (y < 730) {
                    y += 30;
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                    ctx.fillRect(GameCanvas.width / 2, y, 5, 15);
                        ctx.restore();
                }
            }

        function DrawPlayers() {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(playerOne.x1, playerOne.y1, playerOne.x2, playerOne.y2);
            ctx.fillRect(playerTwo.x1, playerTwo.y1, playerTwo.x2, playerTwo.y2);
            ctx.restore();
            requestAnimationFrame(DrawPlayers);
        }
        window.addEventListener("keydown", movePlayer, false);

        function movePlayer(e) {

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GameCanvas.width, GameCanvas.height);

            if (e.keyCode == 83) {
                console.log('S pressed!');
                playerOne.y1 += 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 87) {
                console.log('W pressed!');
                playerOne.y1 -= 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                console.log('Top arrow pressed!');
                playerTwo.y1 -= 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                console.log('Bottom arrow pressed!');
                playerTwo.y1 += 20;
            }
            if (e.keyCode > 0) {
                DrawDashesWhileLoop();
                BarCollision(playerOne);
                BarCollision(playerTwo);
            }
        }
        function BarCollision(player) {
            if (player.y1 < 10) {
                console.log("AAAAAAAA");
                player.y1 = 10;
            }
            if (player.y1 > 820) {
                console.log("AAAAAAAA");
                player.y1 = 820;
            }
        }
        function BallMovement() {
          // console.log('ball moving')
            DrawBall();
            speedX = 10;
            speedY = 10;
            requestAnimationFrame(BallMovement);
        }
        function DrawBall() {
          ctx.clearRect(Ball.x1, Ball.y1, Ball.x2, Ball.y2);
          console.log()
          Ball.x1 += 2;
          ctx.save();
          ctx.fillStyle = "white";
          ctx.fillRect(Ball.x1, Ball.y1, Ball.x2, Ball.y2);
          ctx.restore();
        }
```

```css
#GameCanvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
/*     margin-top: 10vh;
    margin-bottom: 10vh;
    margin-right: 12vw;
    margin-left: 12vw; */
}

body {
    font-family: 'ArcadeFont';
    font-size: 5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArcadeFont';
    src: url('fonts/ARCADECLASSIC.TTF');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Pong.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="GameCanvas">No support for you, scrub!</canvas>
    <!--Start of the script-->
    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

)